# Servor Error even when the code is correct

Tags: node.js, server, hosting

I have used heroku for hosting my web app. The problem is that when someone tries to upload a file on my website it shows internal server error. But when i run the server locally on port 3000 everything works fine and I am able to upload files.

Comment: Where are you saving the uploaded files to?

Comment: To uploads folder. (I am using mongodb)

Comment: Could be a lot of things. Might be a filetype the heroku does not allow, or the container has run out of space or something else. Also keep in mind the Heroku destroys the container and creates new one every time you deploy, so any previously uploaded files would be deleted. I recommend uploading somewhere else like AWS S3, Azure Storage or something similar, and saving the new URL in your mongodb instead of the local path.